# Paypal Donation Button in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, paypal, donations, paypal-buttons

I've created a paypal donation button from paypal business account with all default setting. I copy paste the html into my asp.net page, and it looks fine. The problem is when I click on the button simply nothing happen. Is this because I'm still on localhost? Will it be work and go to paypal page when I upload the website?

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="buttonId">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Your asp.net page probably already has a form tag on it and you may have pasted the PayPal code inside that form. If that's the case it means you ended up with two nested forms inside the html that gets sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asp.net page probably already has a form tag on it and you may have placed the PayPal code inside that form, which won't work. Instead of using the form with the hidden fields that PayPal generated for you, you could just use a link with url parameters. Here's an example (make sure you replace YOUR_BUTTON_ID_HERE with your id):

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=YOUR_BUTTON_ID_HERE">
    <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code helped me to solve it. Other than what you said, I had to change input type to <img> tag too.

Comment: Glad it worked. You are right about the img tag - I've updated the answer, in case anyone else stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon. In your original example, no hosted button ID was provided:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="buttonId">
```

PayPal buttons are hosted on your PayPal account, so in order for the checkout to appear, an ID must be present.

In order to locate the hosted button ID, log in to your PayPal account and go to Tools > PayPal Buttons. Click on the carat next to the button you are trying to add, and the button ID will display. Just substitute that value for "buttonId", and it should be working.

Comment: Well, thanks but I knew it, I just put it like that here, in my code of course I had the ID there.